# Functionals of Karhunen-Loeve expansion

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the Karhunen-Loeve expansion of a stochastic process ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem)) on a finite interval $t \in [a,b]$.

Denote this by $X(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\lambda_k} \cdot Z_k \cdot e_k(t)$

where $Z_k$ are uncorrelated random variables. Are there functionals $Q(X(t))$, not necessarily linear, such that the Karhunen-Loeve expansion of $Q(X(t)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\tilde{\lambda}_k} \cdot Z_k \cdot \tilde{e}_k(t)$?

I.e. the Karhunen-Loeve expansion of $X(t)$ and $Q(X(t))$ depend on the same random variables $Z_k$ but the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are different? For example, I am not looking for an example in which $\tilde{\lambda}_k = c\lambda_k$ for some constant $c$. I guess this rules out the conveniences of employing a Gaussian process for $X(t)$ with linear functionals $Q$?

Comment: Consider $\int_0^t X(s) ds$, or any other integral transform. Of course that's not a local functional.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Hans. I had thought about that too. But I am not so sure if $\int \tilde{e}_k(t) \,dt$ would be an eigenvector of the covariance function of $Q(X(t))$. And of course, the eigenvalue has to be different and solving for it is another thing.